# Variable substitution is not happening inside Containerfile

Tags: asp.net-core, dockerfile, .net-6.0, alpine-linux, podman

- Building a docker container
- Using alpine as build image
- The Containerfile receives VERSION as argument
- It is set as image version
- The same version is passed to dotnet publish command.
- **The passed version (which is a variable) in current context never gets substituted. Instead of substituted variable ${VARIABLE} is passed to dotnet publish command.**

```
    ARG VERSION
    
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine as build
    ARG VERSION
    RUN echo ${VERSION}
    RUN echo ${VERSION} > image_version
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY . .
    RUN dotnet restore
    # TODO Pass the version as build command below.
    RUN dotnet publish --version-suffix ${VERSION} --output /app/published-app
```

I tried different ways to do the variable substitution like below:

- "$VERSION"
- "$(VERSION)"
- $VERSION ..... and many other ways I found in the internet. None of them worked. The argument passed is exactly what it is before the variable is substituted.

Thoughts on what may be causing this?

Comment: You say "The Containerfile receives VERSION as argument" - but it doesn't look like it does. Are you sure that is set in your environment/.env? Or are you setting it with `--build-arg`?

Comment: Yes, it does. You can see in the code I even try to echo the ${VERSION} and it works as expected. It prints out the version that was passed. i.e. 
podman build -t exampleapi --build-arg VERSION=0.0.1  .

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise the "echo" was working. So - if `RUN a` and `RUN b` are showing different effects it must be something to do with the `b`. What happens if you replace that last line with `RUN echo dotnet...` - does it print what you are expecting?

Comment: @ShauravAdhikari you should add the build output to an [edit] of your question, this will show that `RUN echo ${VERSION}` works. Maybe also show a `cat image_version` on a running container out of this image, along with the command line used to build the container.